# Electronic Dance Music, Electronic Direct Mail, or Entity Data Model?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

While editing [Pass a parameter using Button click event into another aspx page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30427871/pass-a-parameter-using-button-click-event-into-another-aspx-page) and working in the comments, it developed that the [edm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edm) tag has at least three different meanings:

1. Electronic Dance Music, largest hit on Google
2. Electronic Direct Mail
3. Entity Data Model

Now, I was about to start going through the [edm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edm) questions and doing some disambiguation, but thought I'd pause to ask the community what we should do about this tag.

Comment: I will be really surprised if someone tagged a question 'edm' and actually meant Electronic Dance Music.

Comment: I was about to make a smart remark about how Electronic Dance Music might well be generated by running the source code of a program through a synthesizer, but then I realized that I actually _like_ the one piece of Electronic Dance Music that I ever heard.

Comment: I think we should always try to avoid abbreviations in tags, unless they're really, absolutely ubiquitous (like XML), or the underlying term is just too long (like XML).

Comment: I love how both examples are XML @gert

Comment: EDM in a musical context is a USAism, so if it's actually that then it's pretty useless. Looking through the questions your other two options seem to cover it. Near miss :-).

Comment: @Ben: what do they call it in the rest of the world. Looking for tag synonyms. :-)

Comment: Just dance, though according to wiki the US is even broader than I thought, so I can give you a [tag:dub] (could be considered a ancestor genre rather than technically dance), but not much else I'm afraid.

Comment: you can go with "C#EDM"

Comment: If anything, it would be .net-edm, since it has nothing to do with the C# programming language and can just as easily be used from VB.NET or even PowerShell.

Comment: Or [Early Day Motions](http://www.parliament.uk/edm)? Apparently, it has something to do with the UK Parliament, but I'd be more inclined to associate it with too much coffee in the morning or a good curry the night before ...

Comment: Perhaps burninate edm? Seeing as it only has 56 questions.... Not going to be missed much, likely.

Comment: Great idea! Note: "ado.net-entity-data-model" already exists

Comment: To properly burninate [edm], you obviously need to use an Electrical Discharge Machining tool.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Just make sure we have an Elimination and Destruction Moderator oversee it.

Answer (score 16):

Proposal as per the comments, Burninate the [edm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edm) tag

Re-tag those that are .net Entity Data Model questions to [ado.net-entity-data-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ado.net-entity-data-model)

Comment: I can't remove a tag, so I added a description and changed the Entity Data Model questions into appropriate tags other than [edm].

Comment: Okay, did the obvious thing and replaced the [edm] tag by a new [electronic-direct-mail] tag.